# Simple Dom HTML changes not taken

Tags: element, simple-html-dom

I use simple_html_dom.php

I want to remove the first child of a element :

The HTML :

```
<div id="result">
<a class="result_type1" href="#">The title</a>
<span class="item">item</span>
<span class="more">more</span> 
<span class="description">description</span>
</div>
```

The PHP test 1 :

```
  foreach($html2->find("div[id=result]") as $element) 
 {


$element->children(0)->outertext=$element->children(1)->outertext;
$element->children(1)->outertext=$element->children(2)->outertext;
$element->children(2)->outertext=$element->children(3)->outertext;
$element->children(3)->outertext="";

echo $element->children(0)->plaintext; 

}
```

Result (not good) :

```
     The title
```

PHP test 2

```
  foreach($html2->find("div[id=result]") as $element) 
 {

$element->children(0)->outertext=$element->children(1)->outertext;
$element->children(1)->outertext=$element->children(2)->outertext;
$element->children(2)->outertext=$element->children(3)->outertext;
$element->children(3)->outertext="";

echo $element->children(0)->outertext; 

}
```

Result (good):

```
       <span class="item">item</span>
```

And I don't get the same item.
With plaintext, I get the element that should be removed

Comment: Could you post the HTML and what you're expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that these three properties (outertext, innertext and plaintext) are separated when the information is processed, as stored in a multidimensional array:

If you make a change to an element with "outerText", the other two properties do not change:

```
element1    plaintext: "text 1",
            outerText: "<span> text 2 </ span>",
            InnerText: "text 1"
```

Same if you make a change with "plaintext".

```
element1    plaintext: "text 2"
            outerText: "<div> text 1 </ div>",
            InnerText: "text 1" .
```

Only the "InnerText" property affects the other two properties ...

```
element1    plaintext: "text 2"
            outerText: "<div> text 2 </ div>",
            InnerText: "text 2"
```

by against if you change an element with "href" it will affect "outertext" value.

```
element1    href :     "link2",
            outerText: "<a href="link2"> </a>",
```

Inversly change with "outerText" not influence "href".

```
element1    href :     "link1",
            outerText: "<a href="link2"> </a>",
```